# react state is throwing `TypeError: setEnd is not a function` error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm passing a state hook to my component and changing the value with conditional statement. why is this happening?

in my root component

```
const [done, setDone] = useState(0);

<FirstStep current={current} end={done} setEnd={setDone} />;
```

and in the component i'm using it inside useEffect

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (
      plateInput != null &&
      mileageInput != null &&
      makeInput != null &&
      bodyInput != null &&
      yearInput != null &&
      kindInput != null &&
      transmissionInput !== null
    ) {
      console.log("object cleared");
      setEnd(current);

      // dispatch(setCompletedStep(current));
    } else {
      console.log("object is not cleared");
      setEnd(current - 1);

      // dispatch(setCompletedStep(current - 1));
    }
  }, [
    plateInput,
    mileageInput,
    makeInput,
    bodyInput,
    yearInput,
    kindInput,
    transmissionInput,
  ]);
```

the error is `TypeError: setEnd is not a function`. why is this happening?

Comment: Include full code of `<FirstStep />`

Comment: where you defined data? Provide full code.

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Without the full code i would rather do something like <FirstStep ... setEnd={ (end) => setDone(end); }.

Comment: @ShriHariL i've included the code

Comment: @MohammedBekele how are you receiving your props in ```<FirstStep />```

Comment: @Re9iNee `function FirstStep(current, end, setEnd)`

Comment: it should be `FirstStep({ current, end,  setEnd }) `

Comment: @ShriHariL yes i did that and it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it  looks like an error when receiving the props in `FirstStep` component,
you need to make sure of some points

- in your root component make sure to import useState from react

```
import {useState}  from 'react';
```

- make sure to pass the props correctly to your nested components

```
const MyRoot = () => {
  const [done, setDone] = useState(0);

  return <FirstStep current={current} end={done} setEnd={setDone} />;
}
```

- make sure to recive th props correctly in your FirstStep component

```
// you can destructuring to get the props  
const FirstStep = ({end, setEnd, current}) => {
  if(data != null){
    setEnd(current);
  } else {
    setEnd(current - 1);
  }
  return <p>test</p>
}
```

UPDATE:
try to set the state inside `useEffect` and use the callback function to check the current instead

```
import {useEffect}  from 'react';


useEffect(() => {
  setEnd(() => {
    if(data !== null) {
      return current
    }else {
      return current - 1
    }
  })
}, [])
```

Comment: try to add the code inside useEffect to avoid unwanted error and also use the callback function to set the state 
 ```
useEffect(() => {
  setEnd(() => {
    if(data !== null) {
      return current
    }else {
      return current - 1
    }
  })
}, [])
```

Comment: it works now. i didn't used the curly brace when i de-structuring the props.